# An $x^n, \ n \in N$ power expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Did anybody met a numerical expansion of the form $$x^3=x+j\sum_{m=0}^{x-1}mx-m^2$$ and what do you think about? note that $j=3!$ The distribution of sum values are similar to pascal's triange distribution. Thank you

Comment: Out of curiosity, why write $j$ instead of writing $6$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the $x^3$ case you give first prove that the sum of the first $(n-1)$ consecutive positive integers is always equal to $\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$ and that the sum of the first $(n-1)$ consecutive squares is always equal to $\frac{1}{6}n(n-1)(2n-1)$

When you have done this you will find that

$$n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^2=\frac{1}{2}n^2(n-1)-\frac{1}{6}n(n-1)(2n-1)=\frac{1}{6}n(n-1)(n+1)$$

and that
$$n+6 \left(\frac{1}{6}n(n-1)(n+1) \right)=n^3$$

It is easy to see that if you multiply 3 consecutive positive integers that this product will have at least one factor 2 and at least one factor 3, hence $\frac{1}{6}n(n-1)(n+1)$ is always integer.

You can now investigate if there is a similar pattern in regard to higher powers.